# My app closes with "Unfortunately, app has stopped" dialogue after the splash loads

Tags: java, android, savestate

I have an app where clicking an image makes a value (goldCount) increase by 1.

When run, the app runs a splash, before starting the app. However, after the splash loads, the app closes, saying "Unfortunately, app has stopped", and I get this list of errors in LogCat - See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gbwd.png).

Here is Code:

```
public class MainClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("LeagueClicker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    public float goldCount = 0.0f;
    Button minionClick;
    TextView textGoldCount;
    String textTotal;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Set fullscreen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);

        goldCount = prefs.getFloat("goldCount", 0.0f);

        //Linking the variables
        minionClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minioncentreid);
        textGoldCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewtop);

        //String which will display at the top of the app
        textTotal = goldCount + " Gold";

        //Setting TextView to the String
        textGoldCount.setText(textTotal);
        textGoldCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "mechanical.ttf");
        textGoldCount.setTypeface(tf);
        textGoldCount.setTextSize(35);

        //Setting onClickListener
        minionClick.setClickable(true);

        minionClick.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.minioncentreid:
                goldCount += 1.0;
                prefs.edit().putFloat("goldCount", goldCount).commit();
                textTotal = goldCount + " Gold";
                textGoldCount.setText(textTotal);
                textGoldCount.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I think it has something to do with the SharedPreferences, as it only happened when I tried implementing them.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please post the logcat as text? Not just an image?

Comment: Try moving `getSharedPreferences("LeagueClicker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` into the `onCreate()` method

Comment: I agree with Delpes advice. pref gives you a null pointer exception on line 18 of your MainClass, because you tried instantiating it outside of onCreate

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to instantiate the `prefs` field using `getSharedPreferences()` before your activity has gone through its creation lifecycle. At this point, you cannot expect the context to be ready for these sorts of invocations.

You could best move this variable instantiation into the `onCreate()` method.

To better understand why this is, I strongly recommend [reading about the activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

put the below line after the  setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout); method.

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("LeagueClicker", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```